# Grails start two in-memory databases for dev/test?

Tags: grails, groovy, reporting, datasource, etl

Is there a way to start up two in-memory databases with grails? Specifically, I'd like to integration test my ETL process and allow reporting to be runnable in both development and test environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the [Datasources Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/datasources)

Comment: Any datasource listed in datasources as 'memory' gets started automatically.